# React Event Handler in Graph Toolkit Custom Template Not Working

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-toolkit

We're templating the flyout in the Microsoft Graph Toolkit login component and click handlers on our own elements (inside the custom template) are not working. We're using a functional component, not a class. Any idea what we're doing wrong? Some of the HTML elements we have are omitted because they aren't relevant for this post. Here's our code:

```js
  const CustomLoginTemplate = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
    const { handleSignOut } = props.dataContext;

    return (
      <div>
          <div className={signOutStyle} tabIndex={0} onClick={handleSignOut}>Sign Out</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

```html
<Login>
   <CustomLoginTemplate template="flyout-commands"></CustomLoginTemplate>
</Login>
```

***Note***: there are two other similar questions here on SO but neither one actually addresses the exact issue we are having here.

Comment: Does invoking the signout like this work for you?: 
onClick={() => handleSignOut()} 

Any errors?

Comment: Try this working sample: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mgt-react-login?file=src/App.js

The mock-provider will have a slight delay for login and logout by design.

Comment: @NicVogt We were using React 16.8.0 and this problem resolved when we upgrade to version 17. We tried a lot of different things and nothing else worked.